# About sending a XML file here

Tags: discussion

This question is not about any programming language, it is about this box where i am typing this question, which is what if i want to paste an XML file here to ask some question about it?

Comment: Questions about using SO belong on [meta].

Comment: Paste the xml text in the box then select the text and click on the {} above the box to format it as code.

Answer (score 3):

Try to only place the relevant part of the file into the box, if each line is indented with 4 spaces it will look like a code block.

At that point you should ask specifically about what part of the snippet you are having an issue with or which is causing problems.

Don't just dump the whole file there unless the entire file is relevant and preferably small.